# Getting erros when using local copy of Bootstrap in Angular6

Tags: angular6

In my project, I have downloaded **local copies** of `Bootstrap`, `Jquery` and `Popper`. But I am getting errors when I include them in the `Angular6` project.

The files are at location `angular-test\src\assets\common`

I have included their paths in `Angular.json` under `projects` property.

```
 "projects": {
    "angular-test": 
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/assets/common/css/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/common/javascripts/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.js",
              "src/assets/common/javascripts/vendor/popper/umd/popper.js",
              "src/assets/common/javascripts/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"
              ]
          },
```

and am using in them in `index.html` as follows:

```
<head>
...
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root signup="success1"></app-root>

    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="popper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

The error I am getting is

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/bootstrap.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
jquery-3.2.1.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:4200/jquery-3.2.1.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
popper.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:4200/popper.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
bootstrap.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:4200/bootstrap.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that as I had already specified the javascripts in `scripts` property in `Angular.json`, I didn't need to explicit add them in `index.html`. I commented the following and it worked

```
<!--script src="jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="popper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script-->
```